# vba does not recalculate a cell format

Tags: vba, excel

I'm struggling with an issue that occures when I try to change the format to a cell using NumberFormat...

The cell contains a text like "00:00:23,45" and is formatted as text. I change its format to "ss.00;@".
When I select the cell in excell I see that the format changed to custom (and in the menu the format is correct), but the text remains "00:00:23,45" until **i double click on the cell and press enter** (then he applies the correct format). I attach the code:

```
Questa_cartella_di_lavoro.Sheets("Foglio1").Range("F14").value = "00:00:23,45"
Questa_cartella_di_lavoro.Sheets("Foglio1").Range("F14").NumberFormat = "ss.00;@"
```

I should see "23,45"

P.S. I already tried `Questa_cartella_di_lavoro.Sheets("Foglio1").calculate`
.

.

.

Thanking you in advance for your help,

Lorenzo form Rome.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel: How to force cell evaluation](http://superuser.com/q/299437/52365)

Comment: Hi GSerg, I saw quickly, but I think it doesn't mention this solution (TextToColumns)

Comment: I would personally not use `TextToColumns` for this. It's a big and complicated mechanism for parsing text files, and I would not be sure there would not be some side effects on some locales or in some circumstances.

Comment: Ah ok, what you'd use instead?

Comment: http://superuser.com/a/299438/52365

Comment: Yes, I tried with cell.value = cell.value, but it did not work...

Comment: GSerg I was trying to debug the code and yes... TextToColumns effects also what it should not... for example, If the first cell of my column is empty, he moves it to the end.... but .value = .value still doesn't work... any ideas? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: set `.NumberFormat` before `.Value`

Comment: Slai done... nothing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
Range("A1:A2").NumberFormat = "@" ' Text format
Range("A1") = Replace("00:00:23,45", ",", ".") ' "00:00:23.45"

Range("A2").NumberFormat = "ss.00;@"
Range("A2") = Replace("00:00:23,45", ",", ".") ' "23.45"
```

but if `,` is decimal separator in your local, then maybe:

```
Range("A2").NumberFormat = "ss.00;@"
Range("A2").FormulaLocal = "00:00:23,45"
```

or

```
Range("A2").NumberFormat = "ss.00;@"
Range("A2") = "00:00:23,45"
Range("A2").Replace ",", "."
```

Comment: I tried this solution, but excel gets the value as text, I don't know why. TextToColumns worked, but it gives me another error

Answer (score 0):

You are placing a **Text** string in a cell.  Changing the `NumberFormat` of that cell will not affect the display of a text string.

It will affect the display of a **Number** placed in the cell.

Comment: so what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the cell value is recognised as text, in which case your formatting will have no effect.

Try storing it as a Date before you put it in the cell, using a variable.

```
Dim cellValue As Date
cellValue = CDate("00:00:23,45")

Questa_cartella_di_lavoro.Sheets("Foglio1").Range("F14").Value = cellValue

Questa_cartella_di_lavoro.Sheets("Foglio1").Range("F14").NumberFormat = "ss.00;@"
```

**EDIT:**

I also got a type mismatch error on the `CDate` line when I tested it - for some reason it couldn't parse the text to a `Date`.  This worked for me though:

```
Questa_cartella_di_lavoro.Sheets("Foglio1").Range("F14").NumberFormat = "ss.00;@"

Questa_cartella_di_lavoro.Sheets("Foglio1").Range("F14").Value = Questa_cartella_di_lavoro.Sheets("Foglio1").Range("F14").Value
```

This sets the cell formatting first, and then re-enters the existing value which Excel converts into the correct data type with the new cell formatting.